# GridGain node start up failure - java.net.ConnectException during node start up

Tags: gridgain

We have a compute grid prototype (GG 6.5.5) that works fine on a local machine (Win7) but when deployed on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2 even a simple node start up fails.

The behavior on the server:

- During the node start up a java socket exception (see below) is thrown several times.
- After the attempts to communicate stop (the exceptions as well obviously) I suppose, nothing happens for 5-10 minutes.
- After the these 5-10 minutes in some cases the node somehow does come up, joins the grid and capable to receive a task. We couldn't establish the pattern of this behavior.

In the beginning we have suspected that the issue might be caused by blocked or used port so we have modified the ports that are used in the config file but it didn't help to resolve the issue.

- In the console output we get a notification from GG that it wasn't fully tested on "Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2", does it mean that GridGain is not compatible with this OS?
- In the future grid will include linux machines as well, is there a list of supported and incompatible linux versions as well as other OS?
- It is important to mention that the server has no internet access, since on the GG start up it attempts to checks if a new version is available, might that be the cause of the issue? No firewall software is installed.
- Is is possible to disable this new version check (possibly some other checks) in order to speed up the node start up process?

I hope there is a solution, many thanks in advance!

The exception:

```
2015-01-08 17:17:10,078 ERROR [main]: Exception on direct send: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.java:2098)
        at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi.sendMessageDirectly(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.jav
        at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi.sendJoinRequestMessage(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.
        at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi.joinTopology(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.java:1599)
        at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart0(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.java:1084)
        at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.java:982)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:220)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:38
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridKernal.startManager(GridKernal.java:1559)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridKernal.start(GridKernal.java:756)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx$GridNamedInstance.start0(GridGainEx.java:1949)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx$GridNamedInstance.start(GridGainEx.java:1289)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start0(GridGainEx.java:832)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:759)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:677)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:524)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:494)
        at org.gridgain.grid.GridGain.start(GridGain.java:314)
        at org.gridgain.grid.startup.cmdline.GridCommandLineStartup.main(GridCommandLineStartup.java:293)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are getting has nothing to do with operating system, be that Windows or Linux. Most likely you have a firewall enabled some place, either locally on your operating system or remotely, and this firewall is blocking traffic in one direction.

Try disabling all software firewalls, and see if the behavior improves. If it does, you then can try re-enabling the firewall and fixing its settings.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, and thanks for the reply! I am not sure what is the exact configuration of our production environment from the network perspective, what I do know is that there is no firewall on the server itself. I suppose the servers are in a sort of a DMZ but there should be no firewall in place to limit the communication between the servers internal servers at all. Since I have to use a part of the production environment disabling the main firewall of the whole network in not an option. Are there more focused/specific steps that can be taken to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Alex_V,

Can you please provide your configuration file?
Please provide the full log of starting node - ggstart.bat -v ...
or add -DGRIDGAIN_QUIET=false to JVM properties.

From the stack trace you provided I see that exception happens on start. Are you able to start nodes on win 2008? How many hosts are there? Are they in 1 network or routing is configured correctly?

1. When you see node frozen, can you please take a threaddump and post it here.
2. Log message that GridGain is not fully tested with Windows Server does not mean incompatibility. Moreover, I would expect it to work. It is just not tested as thorough as other win systems now.
3. Single topology may include win, mac and linux machines with no restrictions or performance impact. Almost all popular linux distributives are supported.
4. You can skip version check by adding -DGRIDGAIN_UPDATE_NOTIFIER=false to the JVM properties, but I dont think it may cause any issues.